# Landing on a "ViewController" on a non-storyboard app on Cocoa

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, uistoryboard

I am new to cocoa development.

When I create a new project on Xcode using storyboards it uses the iOS model, that I like more, of having a viewController and a delegate by those being separate files. Then I start my project using the viewController and adding stuff to its view.

When I create a new project not using storyboards, the "landing page" to start the project is a window and I start by adding views to it.

What I don't like of this model is that I have to add code to the delegate files. I don't like that. I like to have AppDelegate.h and .m just with the coredata and basic code to start the application and pass command to another class.

I simply will not use storyboards anymore on cocoa because they are a sea of bugs and half cooked implementations on Cocoa. NSSavePanel/NSOpenPanel don't work, SplitViewControllers and Tabs work badly. It is a shame.

How do I do that on non-storyboard apps on cocoa? I mean, is it possible to pass control to a viewController or to have another class separate from the app delegate to be the starting point for the app?

Comment: what kind of genius down voted this? Probably someone that don't know the answer. This may be obvious for gurus but I am newbie to OSX and my experience is basically with storyboards on OSX but this time I cannot use them, I have to use the old way with xibs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

In main.m do following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    AppDelegate * delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:delegate];
    [NSApp run];
}
```

In AppDelegate.m following:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic,strong) MainViewController *masterViewController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.masterViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(200, 200, 200, 200)
                                                     styleMask:NSResizableWindowMask
                                                       backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                         defer:NO];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    self.masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
}
```

This will give you resizable view controlled by MainViewController. You will need to create that class and configure it either with XIB or without. You can remove MainMenu.xib from target setting as main interface and from project.

Comment: two questions: if I init the viewController using alloc I will have no xib to add my stuff, right? what do I do with the MainMenu.xib? delete it? Are you sure you are talking about cocoa? you are using UIWindow, UIApplication, UIScreen.. this is ios, not osx.

Comment: missed missing touch part... :-) sorry... my limited understanding of CocoaNotTouch allows me to do things above

Comment: ahhh, now we are talking. THANKS!